# Bindy CRLF for UNMARSHAL

Tags: java, bindy

I wanted to unmarshall a csv file to a Bean.
The issue is the record separator or the newline will be a semi colon ";"
The CSVAnnotation has a crlf separator for marhalling to a csv file. Is there a work around for the reverse scenario. As of now I am replacing the semicolon with a NEWLINE character.

But I might have a requirement where the NEWLINE could be the conventaion "\r\n" or ";"

Any suggestions would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom newline character with

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",", crlf=";")
public Class Order {
...
}
```